# How to update an item in a Json object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json object like this :

```
  {
        "fields" : 
        [
            {
              "name" : "news_title",
              "type" : "text",
              "value" : "old title"
            },
            {
              "name" : "news_content",
              "type" : "textarea",
              "value" : "old content"
            }
        ]            
  }
```

and I have a form that bring me only the values for these fields :

```
Array
(
    [news_title] => My new title
    [news_content] => My new content
    [other_values_doesnt_mach_json_file] => always comes at the end of the array
)
```

My goal is to update that json object with the new values .. so I get the json object with the new values like so :

```
  {
        "fields" : 
        [
            {
              "name" : "news_title",
              "type" : "text",
              "value" : "My new title"
            },
            {
              "name" : "news_content",
              "type" : "textarea",
              "value" : "My new content"
            }
        ]            
  }
```

Here I can loop through the Json object ..

```
$source = json_decode($oldjson);

foreach($source->fields as $field){
        echo $field->name .' - '. $field->value .' <br />';
        //$field->value =  'test'; Here I'm trying to update the values of each field with the new data ..
}
```

And here how I can loop through my new values array ..

```
    // laravel post 
foreach(Input::get() as $name => $value){
    echo $name .' : '. $value .' <br /> ' ;
}
```

But I have no idea how to combine those tow to get a new json object with the new values.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$source = json_decode($oldjson);
$input = Input::get();

foreach($source->fields as $i => $field) {
  echo $field->name .' - '. $field->value .' <br />';
  if (isset($input[$field->name])) {
    $field->value = $input[$field->name];
    //$source[$i] = $field; no need for this line, at least for my main issue above 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot newman! it works fine if I only deleted that last line: $source[$i] = $field; .. If I kept that line, it doesn't work, it adds new items to the final array.. please delete that line and I'll accept it as the correct answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I just edited the answer and commented the last line. I hope you have no problem with that ; )

Comment: hey der ? i m getting invalid argument in foreach () . .i m uploading it in .php file

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
$json = '{"fields":[{"name":"news_title","type":"text","value":"old title"},{"name":"news_content","type":"textarea","value":"old content"}]}';
var_dump($json);

$oJson = json_decode($json) ;
$data = array(
    'news_title' => 'My new title',
    'news_content' => 'My new content',
    'other_values_doesnt_mach_json_file' => 'always comes at the end of the array',
);

foreach ( $data as $key => $val ) {
    foreach ( $oJson->fields as $i => $oVal ) {
        if ( isset($oVal->name) && $oVal->name == $key ) {
            $oJson->fields[$i]->value = $val;
        }
    }
}

$json = json_encode($oJson) ;
var_dump($json);
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, I still get the old json data when I var_dump the new encoded Json.. Thanks a lot

Comment: That means that you did something in different way, because if you copy/paste my code and test it – it works as expected. Nice to hear that you already resolved this. Happy coding :)

Comment: Yeah I had to edit a little things to meet my actual code in my project but I don't think that I missed anything up, I just changed variable names I guess, thanks a lot for your help anyway. really appreciated : )

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extra counter and start tracking input array and json simultaneously as below:

```
$count = 0;
foreach(Input::get() as $name => $value){
   echo $name .' : '. $value .' <br /> ' ;
   $source->fields[$count]->name = $name;
   $source->fields[$count]->value = $value;
}
```

Comment: You have too many dollars (lucky you). What if the 2nd array is in a different order?

Comment: Then you can try creating the JSON rather than updating the existing one in the required order. BTW, how different is the order between the two?

Comment: Actually id didn't get errors, it did when I made some changes sorry for that, but it didn't work, in the first item the value changed from "old title" to 4 ! number 4 (which is the count number of array items) and the other item (new_content value) it kept the same : old content.